# pip._vendor.resolvelib.resolvers.ResolutionTooDeep: 200000

Tags: tensorflow, tfx

I encountered the error "ResolutionTooDeep: 200000" when attempting to install TensorFlow Extended (TFX) on Ubuntu 22.04 using the command 'pip install tfx.'

[Error Picture Install tfx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCo3K.png)

I tried installing TFX using the pip command mentioned above. I expected the installation to proceed without errors, but instead, I received the mentioned error.

PS: Before I installed TFX, I installed TensorFlow, Flask, etc., using this command: "pip install jupyter scikit-learn tensorflow flask joblib".

Comment: The TFX will only work in  Python 3.10

Comment: I've tried using Python 3.10, but still got the error that absl package cannot be downloaded in python ver 3.10 :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out how to install tfx without any error using this command:

```
pip install --extra-index-url https://pypi-nightly.tensorflow.org/simple --pre tfx
```

Thanks to this github issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/issues/5930, I was able to install tfx.

Answer (score 0):

I also believe that this fix has been added in the beta version released today (pip 20.2b1) which can be used by doing `pip install -U pip --pre` which upgrades pip to the beta version.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! But still got the same error :(